# how to open accordion if its inside filter by using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck in some unusual situation. I want to redirect button to the specific page where there are multiple category filters of bike models and similar category models description is mentioned in another page with same kind of filter but the inside filter, there are multiple accordions according to models.

Whenever I am trying to redirect link to particular models and its accordion should open but it is redirecting to only first element. Here is code

[image]

I have tried with adding id after link but its not working because there is filter in between

[image]

```js
// add attempt here


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rm-box").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    if (value == "all") 
    {
      $(".filters").hide('1000');
    }
    else
    {
      $(".filters").not("." + value).hide("1000");
      $(".filters").filter("." + value).show("1000");
    }

    $("ul .button").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })
  })
})


$(document).ready(function() {
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   hash && $('ul.myfilter a[href="' + hash + '"]').panel-body('show');
});
```

```css
/* add helpful css here */

ul.myfilter {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 10px 30px;
}

.myfilter>li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.myfilter>li:hover, .active {
    color: #ff6501!important;
    font-size: 30px!important;
}
.filter-cont{
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.iron-883{
height:400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}

.acco-title:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.acco-title {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ff6501 !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.colorview{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #363636;
    width: 40%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myfilter">
  <li class="button active" data-filter="sportster">Sportster</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="street">Street</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="softail">Softail</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="touring">Touring</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="cvo">Cvo</li>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</ul>

<div class="box filters sportster">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
      <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img iron-883">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt wh-rhs">
        <h4>IRON 883</h4>
        <a class="orng-btn filt-bike-link" href="hdmodels.html#collapse1">Know More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
      <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img forty-8">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt orng-rhs">
        <h4>FORTY EIGHT</h4>
        <a class="white-btn filt-bike-link" href="hdmodels.html#collapse2">Know More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hd-sportster">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
      <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img custom-1200">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt orng-rhs">
        <h4>1200 CUSTOM</h4>
        <a class="white-btn filt-bike-link" href="hdmodels.html#collapse3">Know More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
      <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img hd-roadster">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt wh-rhs">
        <h4>ROADSTER</h4>
        <a class="orng-btn filt-bike-link" href="hdmodels.html">Know More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="myfilter">
  <li class="button active" data-filter="street">Street</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="sportster">Sportster</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="softail">Softail</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="touring">Touring</li>
  <li class="button" data-filter="cvo">Cvo</li>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</ul>

<div class="box filters street">
  <div class="panel-group" id="streetaccordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#streetaccordion" href="#collapse1" class="acco-title">Harley-Davidson Street-750</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Some Code
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: stylesheet / css please

Comment: see that images, there aren't any issue with css I am stuck with the logic how to open specific panel within filter @PunithaSubramaniYoganyaaS

Comment: Can you please share your code css and HTML, in jsfiddle.

Comment: Please update your question to provide a working example and what you have tried.  I see no "accordion" here just some html.  I made a snippet of your code to assist here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss accodion is on another page and link is on another page, There are 5 categories and in those 5 categories each has 2-3 models so 2-3 accordions in each category, Which I have built with filter. if i'm coming from another page by clicking one model It should redirect to that accordion inside category filter instead of always opening first accordion

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to try to figure out ALL your functionality but just address the question.  Note where the element with id `collapse2` is open when this is ran.

I used this reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

I altered some CSS etc. just to show it better in this limited context more clearly. You were close but the key is the selector and then trigger the `show` event. These are the key lines: (comments in the code, note where they are placed)

```
let hash = window.location.hash;
$('#' + hash).collapse('show');
```

Side note, I moved these outside the `UL` since a `UL` can only contain `li` or a nested list item and added a class instead of in-line style:

```
<div class="clear-things"></div>
```

Reference https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

```js
$(function() {
  //$(".rm-box").hide();
  $("ul.myfilter").find(".button").on('color-siblings', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }).on('click', function(event) {
    let filters = $(".filters");
    let value = $(this).data("filter");
    if (value == "all") {
      filters.hide('1000');
    } else {
      filters.not("." + value).hide("1000");
      filters.filter("." + value).show("1000");
    }
    $(this).trigger('color-siblings');
  });

  // code that toggles the collapse in the document ready event handler
  // could also be a custom event trigger like I show for the color above
  let hash = window.location.hash;
  hash = "collapse2"; // just to test - get hash as above
  // assumption of ID here thus the '#', ID MUST be unique so that is OK
  $('#' + hash).collapse('show');
});
```

```css
/* add helpful css here */

div>ul.myfilter {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}


/*so we see it */

ul.myfilter {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.myfilter>li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
  color: #0165ff;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.myfilter>li:hover,
.active {
  color: #ff6501!important;
}

.filter-cont {
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.iron-883 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}

.acco-title:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.acco-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ff6501 !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.colorview {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #363636;
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
}

.clear-things {
  clear: both;
}
.panel-body {border:solid blue 1px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <ul class="myfilter">
    <li class="button active" data-filter="sportster">Sportster</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="street">Street</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="softail">Softail</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="touring">Touring</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="cvo">Cvo</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear-things"></div>
  <div class="box filters sportster">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
        <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img iron-883">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt wh-rhs">
          <h4>IRON 883</h4>
          <a class="orng-btn filt-bike-link" href="#collapse1">Know More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
        <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img forty-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt orng-rhs">
          <h4>FORTY EIGHT</h4>
          <a class="white-btn filt-bike-link" href="#collapse2">Know More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hd-sportster">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
        <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img custom-1200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt orng-rhs">
          <h4>1200 CUSTOM</h4>
          <a class="white-btn filt-bike-link" href="hdmodels.html#collapse3">Know More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 common-for-all">
        <div class="col-md-4 cmn-fit-img hd-roadster">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 cmn-fit-txt wh-rhs">
          <h4>ROADSTER</h4>
          <a class="orng-btn filt-bike-link" href="#collapse3">Know More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="myfilter">
    <li class="button active" data-filter="street">Street</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="sportster">Sportster</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="softail">Softail</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="touring">Touring</li>
    <li class="button" data-filter="cvo">Cvo</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear-things"></div>
  <div class="box filters street">
    <div class="panel-group" id="streetaccordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#streetaccordion" href="#collapse1" class="acco-title">Harley-Davidson Street-750</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Some Code 750 CC
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#streetaccordion" href="#collapse2" class="acco-title">Harley-Davidson Forty Eight</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Some Code Forty Eight Cheese bits
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```